# Eclipse shows error on log4j dependency, but log4j is correctly included

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven project, created using the `quickstart` archetype.

This is my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.dotd</groupId>
    <artifactId>marus</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>marus</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mvnrepository.com</id>
            <name>mvnrepository.com</name>
            <url>http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifacts</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is what I see in Eclipse:

[image]

---

[image]

The fact is that in the maven `.m2` repository the jar exists and is resolved by eclipse, so I'm able to import and use classes from log4j as you can see in the following screenshot.

[image]

Why does eclipse still tell me that the artifact is missing?

**UPDATE**
As pointed out by Juned Ahsan, it could be a repository issue. So I did browse `http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifacts` and it shows a 404 error: the repository doesn't exist.

I switched to the official maven repo, `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/`, but the error persists.

Comment: Try Alt + F5 and check Force Update Snapshots and Releases.

Comment: @JiKra Still no luck

Comment: Is is possible that maven is able to access the repo but that eclipse has problems? Are you sitting behind a proxy?

Comment: @secure_paul Yes, I'm behind a proxy. But I have the settings.xml file with the proxy informations, which is shared with three other projects that doesn't have this issue

Answer (score 0):

Log4j is such a popular library and used by so many frameworks. So it must be transitively injected by maven from any other dependent jar and hence it is available for you in your classpath in eclipse.

You can generate maven dependency tree using [plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html).

Comment: I checked the repo url for `mvnrepository` and it shows a 404 error. So I switched to `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/` but it still doesn't work.